# Groups of continuous integers in a list in Kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin, integer

I have a list of integers placed in order. What I want is to get groups of consecutive integers from the list.

For example:

Input: [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77]

Desired Output: [[19, 20, 21, 22, 23], [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44], [59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66], [73, 74, 75, 76, 77]]

Here is my code:

```
    private fun getConsecutiveNumbers(srcList: ArrayList<Int>): List<List<Int>> {

        val listConsecNums = ArrayList<List<Int>>()
        var subList = ArrayList<Int>()

        for (i in 0 until srcList.size) {
            subList.add(srcList[i])

            if ((i + 1 >= srcList.size) || (srcList[i] + 1 != srcList[i + 1])) {
                listConsecNums.add(subList)
                subList = ArrayList()
            }
        }

        return listConsecNums

    }
```

Here, the code assumes that the numbers are consecutive and collects them in a list until a non-consecutive number is found.

This code works in the general case for what I want, but I was just wondering if there is a more efficient Kolin-y way to do the same.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`fold` with mutable lists. If the element is consecutive, then add it to the last array, otherwise create a new array with this element

```
fun getConsecutiveNumbers(srcList: List<Int>): List<List<Int>> {
    return srcList.fold(mutableListOf<MutableList<Int>>()) { acc, i ->
        if (acc.isEmpty() || acc.last().last() != i - 1) {
            acc.add(mutableListOf(i))
        } else acc.last().add(i)
        acc
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach that is more compact, but it's less efficient because it creates two intermediate throw-away Lists.

First get a list of the indices matching the beginning of each consecutive run. Then zip the range starts and ends to pull out the relevant ranges of the original list. But you have to add an extra value at the end before zipping so the last range can be captured.

```
fun List<Int>.splitByConsecutive(): List<List<Int>> {
    val rangeStarts = mapIndexedNotNull { index, i -> 
        if (index == 0 || i - 1 != this[index - 1]) index else null 
    }
    return (rangeStarts + listOf(size)).zipWithNext(::subList)
}
```

With sequences it doesn't need intermediate lists, but it's still more steps:

```
fun List<Int>.splitByConsecutive(): List<List<Int>> {
    val rangeStarts = asSequence().mapIndexedNotNull { index, i -> 
        if (index == 0 || i - 1 != this[index - 1]) index else null 
    }
    return (rangeStarts + sequenceOf(size)).zipWithNext(::subList).toList()
}
```